# Draw text along the arc on layer

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to add text along the arc and I read the [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-text-along-arc-path/). There is a function as below. I don't quite understand the difference between `Layer` and `Context` and which one I should use. Is a `Layer` `Canvas` plus `Context`?
I created an arc on the layer which is different from the [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-text-along-arc-path/). In `drawTextAlongArc`, how can I draw the text along the arc using `Layer`? Or I have to use `Context` to do the work? It's not working now. But if it works, will the arc be drawn on the layer?

```
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle) {
    var len = str.length, s;
    context.save();
    context.translate(centerX, centerY);
    context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
    context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);
    for(var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
      context.rotate(angle / len);
      context.save();
      context.translate(0, -1 * radius);
      s = str[n];
      context.fillText(s, 0, 0);
      context.restore();
    }
    context.restore();
  }

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "mainContainer",
    width: $("#mainContainer").width(),
    height: $("#mainContainer").height()
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var kineticGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: 300,
        y: 120,
        draggable: true,
        fill: 'black',
        draggable: true
    });
var arc = new Kinetic.Arc({
        innerRadius: 90,
        outerRadius: 92,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        angle: 180,
        rotationDeg: 180
    });

var canvas = layer.getCanvas(),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    centerX = canvas.width / 2,
    centerY = canvas.height - 30;
    drawTextAlongArc(context, 'Text along arc path', centerX, centerY, 92, 180);
    context.stroke();

kineticGroup.add(arc);    
layer.add(kineticGroup);
stage.add(layer);
stage.draw();
```

Comment: Check out Kinetic.TextPath: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-path-tutorial/

Comment: @markE Can Kinetic.TextPath change the arc by dragging anchors? By changing the svg data or the scale?

Comment: Change the arc by dragging with anchors---where did that come from?.  None of the path (or arc) commands provides automatic drag-reshaping. You would have to code anchors and respond to drags accordingly.  You would probably want to use the Kinetic.Path to do the drag-shaping and then use the data defined by the dragging to create a Kinetic.TextPath since TextPath does not let you reset its data property.  Such coding is somewhat complex because it involves quite a few moving parts.

Comment: @markE I also got this one by following your advice. I added two anchors at the ends of the arc. By dragging them, change the svg data of the `Path`, destroy the `TextPath` and redraw a new one. Thank you again!